# Unrecognized \001\000 at the end of string..?

Tags: c++, arduino

I use a NRF24L01 Module to communicate with 2 arduino..

I send this:

```
const char hello[32];
memcpy(hello, "World", 5);
```

now, I receive on the other side this:

"World\001\000\000\000"

how can I clean my string or what's that?

thanks,
daniel

Comment: that should not compile.  You can't write to a `const` location!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not copying the string literal's null terminator, so you would need to specify 6 instead of 5:

```cpp
memcpy(hello, "World", 6);
```

Except that `hello` is an array of `const` characters, so you actually can't write to it, only initialize it. Your `memcpy()` is *undefined behavior*.

Use this instead:

```cpp
const char hello[32] = "World";
```

That will initialize the array's first 5 characters, and zero out the rest for you.

Answer (score 2):

`"World"` is of type `const char[6]`. You are missing the null-terminator.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal